# is model object available after deletion?

Tags: django

If I get all objects from the database, then iterate through them with a python foreach loop, then I delete all of them in the loop. What happens to the deleted database entries that are still in memory as customer object

```
for cust in Customer.objects.all():
   #delete all
   for cust2 in Customer.objects.all():
      cust2.delete()

   #what is cust now??
   cust.save() # is this valid?
```

Would it be possible to refresh the values in each iteration for each cust immediately? So that while processing cust1, I delete cust2, then in the next iteration I don't start to process cust2... imagine this:

```
   for cust in Customer.objects.all():
       if cust.pay_everyone():
           for cust2 in Customer.objects.all(): 
               cust2.paid = True
               cust2.save()

       #when cust2 comes in the loop, cust2.paid is still False
       #the previous pay_everyone() method is undone
       if cust.kill_everyone():
           for cust2 in Customer.objects.all(): 
               cust2.delete()

       #when cust2 comes in the loop, he is still alive when he should be dead
       cust.save()
       # in cust2's turn in the loop, he has been just resurrected which is not possible
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an excerpt taken from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete):

> Model.delete([using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
>   Issues a SQL DELETE for the object. This only deletes the object in the database; the Python instance will still exist and will still have data in its fields.
>
> For more details, including how to delete objects in bulk, see Deleting objects.
>
> If you want customized deletion behavior, you can override the delete() method. See Overriding predefined model methods for more details.

I don't get why you would nest a second loop like that inside the first one: for each object, delete all the objects then save the object?

```
cust = Customer.objects.all():

#delete all
for c in Customer.objects.all():
   c.delete()
```

this is clearer, imho. I'll try explain what SHOULD happen (not 100% sure, never tried something like that).

- cust is a QueryDict object and, as the docs say, it still populted
- your DB is now emptied of all the data related to the Customer Model

You should now be able to iterate through cust and save each object back again.

Mind the **should**, it's very important

Comment: Doesn't mind, cust2 and cust are two different copies of the Customer, they both contain the same data and saving cust at the end will put its values back in your db. your cust2 loop is just deleting data from the db, but the outmost Customer loop stores a temporary queryset containing the initial values from the database. It doesn't mind if your inner loop deletes them all, the Customer.objects.all() still contains the original values

Comment: I guess the only solution to avoid this synchronization error is to refresh each cust manually in the beginning of the loop. something like `cust = cust.refresh()`

Answer (score 1):

The `cust`variable contains a python representation of informations about the n-th element stored in the QuerySet (obtained by Customer.objects.all()).

If you call the delete() method you hit the DB but all informations about your deleted object are still stored in the `cust`variable. Thus, if you call after deleting the save() method on this, you store anew in the DB all informations that was contained in the variable.